# Generics with multi threads and instance sharing

Tags: java, generics, garbage-collection

I have a generic class that can be sketched like this

```
public class Shared<T extends EntityBase> {

    private HashMap<String, Class<? extends Executor<T>>> classes;
    private HashMap<String, ? super Executor<T>> instances;
    private List<Entity> entities;
    private Compiler compiler;

   // Constructor and getters

    public void put(Entity entity, Source source) {
        Class<?> cls = compiler.load(source);
        put(entity, (Class<? extends Executor<T>>) cls );

    }

    private void put(Entity entity, Class<? extends Executor<T>> cls) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
        classes.put(entity.getId(), cls);
        instances.put(entity.getId(), cls.newInstance());
        entities.add(entity);
    }
}
```

In my application this class is instanced **once** and several independent threads access it.

In particular a single thread is responsible of writing to it and several access its instances Map via a getter.

When I receive a `Source` instance and call the `private put` method, both maps and the list are updated.

In a debugging session with `InteliiJ` when the **frame** of the `Singleton` class is exited the this class losses its state and both `Map` and the `List` became empty once again.

How may I explain that? Why the `Class<? extends Executor<T>>` instances and the `? super Executor<T>` instances are lost?

Answer (score 1):

generics are effectively just part of the compiler's imagination; at runtime that's all gone. Therefore, the generics in this example have absolutely nothing to do with what you're witnessing.

The code as pasted cannot produce the effect you see (where the map first changes, then reverts). But, more generally, if you are calling 'put' from different threads, this code is broken. There are no guards in place to prevent synchronous access. When you update a map simultaneously from different threads, the map spec specifically says anything can happen (In that sense, the map just resetting to empty is technically 'according to spec', in that anything is allowed because you're not doing the threading issue right).

The easy fix is to mark your second put method as 'synchronized'.

An alternative strategy is to use lists and maps from the `java.util.concurrent` package. However, no amount of using that will ever let you have `classes`, `instances` and `entities` be guaranteed in sync with each other. Only `synchronized` can do that.

Comment: The `put` methods were marked as `synchronized` and I've replaced the `HashMaps` with `ConcurrentHashMaps`. The other change is that the `Keys` of both `ConcurrentHashMaps` are now `Entity` instances instead of `String` instances. Now this `Shared` instance does not `loose` its `Objects` in both `ConcurrentHashMaps`. Not sure if its related with the `String pool` in some strange way or not. Thanks for your interest though

Comment: @JorgeLavín this has been answered already. Your original code was broken, because it was not thread safe. It had nothing to do with Generics, nothing with garbage collection, and nothing with a string pool. Just multi-threading.